# Remove default sorting "order" form DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable and I want to remove default sorting order. I tried to do it like this:

`"order": [[-1, "asc"]]` or `"order": false`

It works but it also removes the paginate and searchbox and I don't want that.

How can I do it?

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Estatus</th>
            <th>Tipo Documento<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Nº Electrónico<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Fecha<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
            "order": [[-1, "asc"]]
        });

    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```html
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
              "ordering": false,
              "paging": true,
              "search": true,
              "info": true
          });

      $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

  });
</script>
```